# Review of linked list and quick sort

Tags: java, linked-list, quick-sort

I was trying another approach of sorting a linked list. Aside from the available methods, I've decided to take each node from the linked list and place it into an array.  With that, I would be able to compare the data variables easily. I applied `quickSort()` on the array, and this is what I have.  I would appreciate any feedback/comments on my code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();

        Student s = new Student(1, "John", 20, "Italy", "2011");
        list.addStudent(s);
        Student s2 = new Student(2, "Mark", 19, "UAE", "2010");
        list.addStudent(s2);
        Student s3 = new Student(3, "Sally", 35, "UAE", "2000");
        list.addStudent(s3);

        System.out.println("Students in the list: ");
        list.print();

        Node[] n = list.convertA(list);
        quickSort(n, 0, (n.length-1));
        System.out.println("Sorted list is:");

        for(int q =0;q<n.length;q++){
            System.out.println(n[q] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static int partition(Node arr[], int left, int right) {

        int i = left, j = right;

        Node tmp;

        Node pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j) {

            while (arr[i].getStudent().getAge() < pivot.getStudent().getAge()) {
                i++;
            }

            while (arr[j].getStudent().getAge() > pivot.getStudent().getAge()) {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {

                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
                i++;
                j--;

            }

        }
        return i;

    }

    public static void quickSort(Node arr[], int left, int right) {

        int index = partition(arr, left, right-1);

        if (left < index - 1) {
            quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
        }

        if (index < right) {
            quickSort(arr, index, right);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I don't know why are you trying to *reinvent the wheel?* Java has a strong and beautiful API with many methods and there is also [a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) for sorting an custom array. Which is more faster than *quicksort*. However I think this is for your own practice.

- Your `convertA` method is not good, cause you are passing the reference as argument as well. So either make the method static or use the existing method `toArray()`.
- You are converting a student list to an `Node` array, why? change `Node` array to `Student` array. So this

  ```
  arr[i].getStudent().getAge()
  ```

  will change to

  ```
  arr[i].getAge()
  ```
- there is a possible bug you are calculating `(left + right) / 2` which may cause an overflow, though Java `int` range is very big you will face the overflow very rarely, but if you want to fix this; change to `(right - left) / 2 + left`.

Check How Other Have Done The Quicksort :

[From CodeReview 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6939/quick-sort-implementation?rq=1)

[From CodeReview 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4022/java-implementation-of-quick-sort?rq=1)

[Why you should use the API method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154158/why-collections-sort-uses-merge-sort-instead-of-quicksort)